# Getting a 414 Request-Uri Too Long from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, http, microsoft-graph-api, odata, microsoft-graph-teams

I use the Microsoft Graph API to list Teams shifts. For this, I make use of the [list shifts endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The response can be [paginated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?context=graph/api/1.0) and, in my case, at some point I get an `@odata.nextLink` that returns me an `HTTP 414: Request-Uri Too Long`.

Is there something I can do around that?

Comment: SkipToken is generated from server-side due to server-side paging, so you can  use $top and odata:nextLink to do paging when querying large data. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

Comment: Also see you can set the header works. Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=YOUR_PAGE_SIZE

Comment: The thing is that the `$skipToken` that is generated is more than 8000 characters long, hence the 414 status.

Comment: hmm, interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue.

You can use JSON batching as a workaround for running these requests because the lengthy URL simply becomes part of the request payload.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching#bypassing-url-length-limitations-with-batching

which moves the too-long URL into the body of the POST.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue. The 414 response is included in the response body instead:
`{ "responses": [ { "id": "1", "status": 414, "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, "body": { "error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "", "innerError": {} } } } ] }`

Comment: @flappy did you overcome this problem?